# Spring MVC 3.1 load controllers dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am using Spring MVC 3.1 for my web project and I have a particular use case. I have to allow users to drop a jar file which has @Controller for RequestMapping that needs to be loaded dynamically. In other words, I do not have an option to restart the Tomcat or the Context (War). How can I do this.

Comment: Maybe [tag:osgi] and [tag:spring-dm]?

Answer (score 0):

not sure this will solve problem or not but you can try out reloading application context by

```
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).refresh();
```

this has some cons also so make sure you really need this situation.

In one of project i had very small requirement like this but i had solved it using JSPs (kind of hack).

Comment: It loads the class with the controller annotation but Dispatcher Servlet cannot identify the path. Here is the output...

Comment: `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test/call
AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test/call]
DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@f41af6] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springServlet'
AbstractUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/test/call]`

Comment: Sanjay did you get any solution for this?